# Linear Algebra exercises available online?

Tags: linear-algebra, online-resources

Is there a good source of undergraduates linear algebra problems available on line?

Do you have any better idea of how to resharpen my linear algebra skills?

Comment: Why wouldn't you borrow a linear algebra book with exercices and solutions at your library ? There are certainly some very good ones.

Comment: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/ there are assignments as well as lectures

Comment: @Klaus, not everyone has accessible math library nearby. But indeed, that would be the best idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert in guiding you but do problems to make your concepts more clearer and clearer. As Klaus points out there are very good texts in Linear Algebra. Just borrow them and work out the problems. Let me lists some good texts:-

- Linear Algebra by Hoffman Kunze
- Linear Algebra by S.Friedberg, A.Insel and Lawrence Spencer.
- Linear Algebra Problem Book,by Paul Halmos.
- Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces, by Paul Halmos.
- PROBLEMS AND THEOREMS IN LINEAR ALGEBRA V. Prasolov link [here](http://mathsouls.110mb.com/Ebook/Math/En/Linear%20Algebra/Problems%20and%20Theorems%20in%20Linear%20Algebra.pdf)

Just go through all of them ans see which one suits you the best. I liked the Friedberg book on linear Algebra. Michael Artin's Algebra book also has good amount of Linear Algebra in it. You may like to see that as well. These books will all be available at **library.nu**

Moreover, if you are unable to solve a problem or understand a concept, please visit this site and the experts will be happy to help you out.

Happy Reading!!!

Comment: +1 for Prasolov's book. Great book which is not that well known.

Answer (score 0):

So here are three links to online resources on linear algebra:

http://mathsouls.110mb.com/Ebook/Math/En/Linear%20Algebra/Problems%20and%20Theorems%20in%20Linear%20Algebra.pdf

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/

https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/sergei-treil-homepage/linear-algebra-done-wrong

Answer (score 0):

Those above are probably right about just getting a book, in particular as chandru says, Hoffman and Kunze.

However you might be happy with this book: https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/sergei-treil-homepage/linear-algebra-done-wrong

It is actually a text book, but It has some good problems.